# Can I use Shimano Claris shifter to my Shimano Tourney road bike

Tags: road-bike, shifter, compatibility

Planning to upgrade my road bike and buying a Shimano claris because my bike shifter still thumb shift

Can I use a 8 speed Shimano Claris shifter to my 7 speed Shimano Tourney ?

Answer (score 2):

No. The sprocket spacing gets narrower as the number of sprockets goes up - to keep the cassette width constant (until 11 speed where it gets slightly wider).

An 8 speed shifter will not index correctly as it is pulling cable length increments for 8 speed spacing not 7 speed.

Tourney isn't really compatible with any Shimano components in the levels above it, so a better route to go would be to replace the entire groupset (you can probably get away with not upgrading the crank).

Many people in this community feel that Tourney level bikes are not worth spending money on upgrading, and it's better to sell them and buy a whole new bike a step up.

Comment: Yeah, Claris derailleurs and cassettes are pretty cheap but the new brifter is a bit more expensive. And it would probably feel really weird to ride with different brifters on each side, so you'd probably want a pair of them, and then I don't know if you need a new front derailleur as well.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no it will not work well.

The reason being that an 8 spd shifter has a different cable pull than a 7 spd shifter. For Shimano specifically the 8 spd shifter will pull the cable 2.8mm per shift while the 7 spd shifter will pull the cable 2.9mm per shift (source: https://www.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/)

So while you might be able to prevent the shifter from overshifting by using the derailleur limit screws, you will never be able to index the gears perfectly because of the different cable pull amounts.

Comment: Good point. What if they had an 8 speed cassette... or in other words what would they need as well as the shifters to make it work?

Comment: I think you would need an 8 speed cassette, shifter, and derailleur. Since the total width of the cassette is 35.4mm for 8 speed and 32.4 for the 7 speed your derailleur would not be able to move across the full range of gears (source:https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-spacing.html). You could probably get it to work without replacing the derailleur but I don't think you would be able to use all 8 gears.